# Why does inserting a second keyframe make blender overwrite the first keyframe?

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I'm kinda new to blender and also English is not my native language, so sorry for that. The main goal is to animate "Transform Randomization" of multiple objects.

So I'm trying to setup two keyframes of animation, where for the first keyframe the cubes are already randomized and positioned right, and for the second keyframe the cubes go on their native places and make a flat surface.

[image]

But when I'm trying to add second keyframe where all the cubes make flat surface - blender kinda ignores everything it memorised and works with new coordinates, so the first keyframe is ruined, and both keyframes are flat surface. It just kinda unavailable to register the action right when I randomize transform.

[image: Transform Randomization, that I want to use again to make cubes go back and make a flat surface]

[image]

As you can see both of keyframes now have the cubes making flat surface, instead of animation of randomized cubes falling into their native places making a flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow solved the problem my self. I think i did something wrong with keyframes from the beginning so the coordinates were both the same no matter what.